Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `present?' for nil
My project is expo bare workflow. It was working fine with old macOS. I updated my macOS to Sequoia, I installed all the packages with yarn. When I tried to 'pod install' in ios directory: this error occurred.
 ios/Podfile:38
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'myVisions' do
 >    use_expo_modules!
 #    config = use_native_modules!

In my BareWorkFlow expo project: in ios directory; I tried to install the pods using 'pod install';
Error: [!] Invalid Podfile file: undefined method `present?' for nil.
